Horizontal alignment when using titletoc and microtype?
In this example, I'm having trouble understanding a couple items.

Why, in the TOC, do the Chapter titles with roman numerals, although very close to centered, appear to be aligned vertically by the first letter "C" rather than "truly" centered such that wider roman numerals push the "C" to the left?

Added: I don't know if there is a way to use \contentslabe[...]{...} or not and have the Chapter I-V. centered; but, if change that code in the MWE to this below, then they center as expected. It appears that, when using \contentslabe[]{} the box for the label is positioned relative to the name, and only the name is centered.
\titlecontents{chapter}
[20pt]
{\scshape}
{\centering\normalsize\chaptername~\ttfamily\thecontentslabel.
\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=1}
{\vspace{-5pt}\\ \hfill {\scriptsize Page.} \vspace{0pt}\\}
{\vspace{5pt}\\}
\parindent -20pt \indent}
{}
{\indent \titlerule*[1pc]{.}\textsf{\footnotesize\contentspage}}
[\vspace{15pt}]


In looking at the chapter title pages, the Chapter with \thecontentslabel centered above the the chapter title, it looks okay at first, but if set the title to the same as the label (as did for Chapter III. on page 9) it can be seen that they do not center when using the microtype package. Why? What am I doing wrong?
I edited the question (updated the code of \titlecontents{chapter} and the image of the TOC; and added this 3.) to ask if it is possible to move the Page. header a bit further to the rigth to be above the page numbers.

I'm sure I'm overlooking the obvious or doing something stupid. Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5.0in,
 textheight = 9.0in,
 headheight = 15pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[newparttoc,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% Comment out, and it aligns centered horizontally.
\usepackage[expansion=false,shrink=0]{microtype}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\huge\ttfamily \vspace*{\fill}}
{PART\nobreakspace\thepart.%
\vspace{15pt}\\%
\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\%
\vspace{-10pt}
}
{0mm}
{}
[\vspace*{\fill}]

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large \ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{}{\pagebreak\vspace*{15pt}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.} \scshape}
{}
{\vspace{10pt} \\ \centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{20pt}]

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.} \scshape}
{}
{\vspace{10pt} \\ \centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{20pt}]

\titlecontents{chapter}
[20pt]
{\scshape}
{\centering\normalsize \chaptername~ \contentslabel[\ttfamily\Rom{\thecontentslabel}.]{0pt}
\ifthenelse{\thecontentslabel=1}
{\vspace{-5pt}\\ \hfill {\scriptsize Page.} \vspace{0pt}\\}
{\vspace{5pt}\\}
\parindent -20pt \indent}
{}
{\indent \titlerule*[1pc]{.}\textsf{\footnotesize\contentspage}}
[\vspace{15pt}]

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\LARGE\centering
\ifthenelse{\thechapter=0}
{}
{\ifthenelse{\thechapter=1 \and \equal{\thepart}{I}}%
{{\Huge HOW TO STUDY THIS BOOK.}\\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
}
{}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\linespread{1.2}\centering\chaptername~\Rom{\thechapter}.}}
{0pt}
{\ifthenelse{\thechapter=3}{\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}} }
%[]

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% Remove the vertical space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \scshape \centering #1\par\nobreak
%     \vskip 10\p@
%     \centering \hskip 0.5em \pgfornament[width=2.2cm]{80}
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\part{Title of first part.}

\chapter{Title of first chapter.}

\chapter{Title of second chapter.}

\chapter{Chapter III.}

\chapter{Title of fourth chapter, long such that it wraps to display an ``indent'' on the second line.}

\chapter{Title of fifth chapter, long such that it wraps to display an ``indent'' on the second line.}

\part{Title of second part.}

\end{document}

The TOC.

Chapter III. with using microtype package.

Chapter III. without microtype package.


you are adding as a space after Page. : {\scriptsize Page.}SPACE

\thechapter should be the print form of the chapter counter (so Roman) so should never be tested numerically such as \ifthenelse{\thechapter=3} (\value{chapter} is the numeric value of the chapter counter) but also why is the formatting adjusting the spacing for specific chapter numbers???

@DavidCarlisle Thank you; I missed that  space; fixed it and "Page." now aligns to the right edge. If you mean the spacing after the chapter being adjusted by chapter numbers, then the reason is it is added only for this example such that it is easier to see that the "Chapter III." is not centered when using microtype. I changed the \ifthenelse to use \value{chapter}; and \value{part} made it possible to not use \equal to test a string on I. However, I don't understand about \thechapter being Roman because it's an arabic number when printed (using Kile in Linux). Thanks.

You should have defined thechapter to be Roman{chapter} then all numbering and references to chapters would use that form

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. I tried doing that and items 1 and 2 remain the same. (I know you did not suggest that it would change those.) I thought perhaps the centering in the TOC was being based on the Arabic chapter number and then displayed in the same position converted to Roman.

ad 2) the difference is that there is margin kerning on the right (the period) in one case, not in the other, hence the shift. you can prevent this margin kerning by adding \noprotrusion at the end of the box: \titleformat{\chapter}[block] ... {\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\linespread{1.2}\centering\chaptername~\Rom{\thechapter}.\noprotrusion}} ...

@Robert Thank you,very much. That fixed it in the real document.
